# PHP: Run function on multiple strings

Tags: php

I am currently using `rtrim()` to remove trailing newlines from strings. Is there a more efficient way to run the following commands?

```
$a = rtrim($a);
$b = rtrim($b);
...
$z = rtrim($z);
```

(Note, `$a` .. `$z` are just placeholders, they're not the real variable names)

These variables are being created through the following function

```
foreach ($xml->xpath('//hardware') as $hwprofile) {
        $machine .= $hwprofile->machine . "\n";
        $count .= $hwprofile->ProcessorInfo->count . "\n";
        $speed .= $hwprofile->ProcessorInfo->speed . "\n";
        $type .= $hwprofile->ProcessorInfo->type . "\n";
        $arch .= $hwprofile->ProcessorInfo->architecture . "\n";
}
```

I want to trim those variables because they all have trailing newlines

Comment: put the strings into an array and use array_map / array_walk :)

Comment: Is that more efficient? Even if it is, it won't be by much :P

Comment: I guess it won't be more efficient but I am looking to keep my code short

Comment: Depends on how the variables get declared ;)

Comment: Where are `$a`, `$b`, etc. coming from, and what are you doing with them? I think this will influence how they could be handled more efficiently.

Comment: @Marc see original post for how I am creating variables

Comment: If the variables are the ones created in the loop ($machine, $count, etc) - you don't need to trim them, just don't add the newline character to the end?

Comment: I need to add the newlines between every line EXCEPT the last one. The foreach runs ~5 loops

Comment: @Bijan So were are we with this question?

Comment: I chose your solution because it was simple and worked.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should work for you:

Just fill the array `$items` with your variable names. Then it loops through all variables and with [`variable variables`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) and rtim's them.

```
$items = range("a", "z"); //your variable names e.g. $items = ["machine", "count"]

foreach($items as $item) {
    $$item = rtrim($$item);
}
```

Another variant which you could also use, since you said you need a new line between every line expect the last one, just create an array like this:

```
foreach ($xml->xpath('//hardware') as $hwprofile) {
        $machine[] = $hwprofile->machine;
        $count[] = $hwprofile->ProcessorInfo->count;
        $speed[] = $hwprofile->ProcessorInfo->speed;
        $type[] = $hwprofile->ProcessorInfo->type;
        $arch[] = $hwprofile->ProcessorInfo->architecture;
}
```

And if you need it now just use:

```
implode(PHP_EOL, $machine);
```

Comment: @PedroLobito I think that it is optional if you used `foreach(): ... endforeach;`

Comment: @sємsєм No it's "always" optional if you don't put bracket just the next expression is in the foreach loop (e.g. `foreach(range(1, 10) as $v);` <- See the semicolon that gets "executed" 10 times)

Comment: This is to make the process "easier", but in what way is this **more efficient**? It uses more resources.

Comment: You are right I have made [**this demo**](http://ideone.com/mfCEU0) and it works without brackets.

Comment: @AlejandroIván If you are asking what is more efficient with the foreach loop with or without brackets, then the answer is both are the same.

Comment: @Rizier123 no. The OP asked for a **more efficient way** of calling `rtrim()`. If we talk about efficiency (resource utilization), this is not more efficient, as the process require more processing power to complete (accessing pointers). This is what I ask.

Comment: @AlejandroIván I think *efficient* is always pretty unspecific. You can write efficient code: lines wise (e.g. small amount of lines), performance wise (e.g. how fast the code is), readable/maintainable (e.g. how good you can read and change a code)

Answer (score 0):

So I think a cleaner solution is that instead of appending strings in each iteration, and then trimming, you could do the following:

The variables that are currently strings and appended each time become arrays. 
For each iteration, append the values to the appropriate array **without** the new line character.

When you need to use the value call implode("\n", $array) and it will join the values with a newline or whatever other separator you choose

Comment: I exactly posted my updated answer as you posted this answer :)

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient way of removing those trailing newlines is to do it inside the function (`foreach` loop in your case) that generates it.

Processing them after being created uses more resources (memory allocations, interpretation, change values from a variable, etc).

If you want to make the processing **easier to write**, then the other answers should be fine.

Don't confuse **efficiency** (which is making a function to process something in a better/less expensive way) with **cleaner/easier to write code**.